# After Server reboot, can't remotely connect from Windows 7 machines

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ssh, samba

Okay, so some background info:
We have a linux server in our data closet which we all connect to over the network to access files.  File sharing was set up with SAMBA.  I also set up SSH with PuTTY to remote into the terminal.  And I also have VNC Viewer to remotely connect to the Ubuntu Desktop.  Also had Ajenti set up for it.

Previously all 4 ways of connecting to the server worked.

Today, someone reset the power in the data closet because something wasn't working for them (not really sure what).  This reset the power to everything including router and the server, etc...

I don't think rebooting the server alone should have affected any of the above services... considering I'm certain I rebooted the server a couple times while setting all that up.

This is where things get weird...  So the connection to the server is super faulty right now but not totally gone...  When I try to connect to the server any of the 4 ways I mentioned(SAMBA fileshare, PuTTY, VNC & Ajenti), I'll get some kind of error.  However, randomly, for short increments of time, the connection will be restored and working exactly how it's supposed to be on all or some.. it truly is random, sometimes i can connect to the fileshare and VNC remote session for a minute but can't SSH.  I'll also get different errors trying to use the same program, seems to be nonsensical... Any time I look up a fix for each service individually, the fixes are too closely related to the software rather than the network connection to it.

I can Ping my Ubuntu server just fine..

My Ubuntu server shows up under NETWORK in windows explorer although I can't access it.. which probably gave me the best piece of information I'll need to solve this:

[image: Windows Network Diagnosis ERROR]

'The device or resource is not set up to accept connections on port "the file and printer sharing (SMB)"'

I've researched the error but I couldn't find a viable solution for my setup.  I'm lost, i feel like this should be a super simple solution but I've been at it for hours now.  I've looked at the services above, they're all running (maybe another service turned off after reboot that is essential?). I've restarted each of them.. I tried rebooting the server again... checked my smbd.conf file to make sure it hadn't reverted back to defaults..

This is frustrating because everything appears to be the exact way it's supposed to be and it should work. ...and it DOES work... for like a minute.. i don't know.  any help would be appreciated.

*EDIT*
Starting to think it has to be a Network Card issue or something.  Based on the random nature of my issue.   On my Ubuntu Machine, I ran a couple internet speed tests, they'd either not complete due to an "issue with the network" or complete really sluggishly although it would reveal the correct download and upload speeds which are fast..

Comment: Does your server get it's IP address from the router via DHCP ? Could something else on the network have the same IP ?

Comment: Yes I believe the server obtained the IP from my router.  I'm doubtful about anything having the same IP address.  The office I'm in in small, I haven't noticed any new tech come in that needs an IP address. and the connection was fine prior to the power being switched off.

Comment: It might be worth doing a quick and easy test. Ping your router. Then disconnect the router LAN cable and ping it again. I'm sure your right, but I have seen IP addresses be assigned incorrectly a few times when part of a network loses power.

Comment: So I ran a few ping tests from my Ubuntu machine.  I pinged my router 3 times... First I got 50% packet loss, 0% packet loss and then 100% packet loss

Comment: OK. So now ping your server. Then disconnect its LAN cable and ping the server again.

Comment: Okay! i see what you mean.  So when I disconnected the server from the Network and I pinged the address, i came back with 0% loss.

Comment: I typed 'arp -a' in cmd.  The IP that is supposed to correspond with my Ubuntu Server had a different physical address than my actual server.

Comment: So the MAC address of the server has changed ? On which machine did you run the arp command ? ( I will confess that I don't use the arp command a great deal). Has your server got more than one ethernet card ? Is your router configured with mac address reservations for your machines (well, your server in particular) ?

Comment: I ran arp on my Windows Desktop.  Regardless the server is connected or not, the IP address pops up with a different Hardware Address than what it tells you when you look at the Connection Information on the Ubuntu desktop

Comment: It looks like the IP is set to dynamic, gunna have to change that...  and I'm unsure about multiple ethernet cards,  But I'd assume so, it has multple ethernet ports.  the server is an HP ProLiant ML150 g6

Comment: I think you probably want to give your server a statuc IP, else it can easily be assigned a different IP if the router reboots. As a test, give your Server a static IP (as you suggest). Maybe configure it in the router ? (Thats what I do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:  IP was originally set up dynamically,  which caused issues when the router was reset and i guess it gave another device the same IP.  So I changed the /etc/network/interfaces file to set up a static IP address for my server.  Now everything reconnects properly.  thanks Mad hatterman!